# How to disable incremental compilation in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, devpartner

How can I disable `Incremental Compilation`?

I am using DevPartner and it complains while instrumenting the code that `Skipping instrumentation due to incremental compilation`.

Comment: Why did you tag this VS2010?  Sounds to me you are actually using VS6

Comment: How old is this DevPartner tool you are using?  It is giving error messages from the previous century.  Document the exact name and version number.

Comment: hahaha.... the exactr name - DevPartner Studio, Version - 10.6.358.0

Comment: Incremental compilation (/Gi) was a VS6 option.  However, some of its features are present in /Gm (minimal rebuild including by class) and /Gy (function level linking).  Have you tried turning those off?  Also try turning off all optimizations.

Answer (score 7):

There are two spots that need to be changed:  In the C/C++ Code Generation options, set "Enable Minimal Rebuild" to "No (/Gm-)".  The second spot is in the Linker General options, where you need to set "Enable Incremental Linking" to "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)".

Apart from messing up instrumentation, incremental building results in debug symbols (PDB) files that are somewhat messed up and cannot always be read reliably.

BTW, there is a newer build of DPS available: 10.6.494.1.  It is about 30% faster when testing instrumented code.

Answer (score 2):

That was a bug in passing the compiler switches between the front end and the back end when we re-architected the instrumentation pieces to allow /MP multi processor compilation. It is fixed in the 494 build mentioned above as well as in a few downloadable patches. Contact Support and they will get you the path to the FTP site.

Sorry for the problems you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2010, Disabling Configuration properties | C/C++ | Code generation | "minimal build" avoids the error.